# Semaphore CI error when deploying to Amazon Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, semaphore-ci

I have just set up CI for a new project that I am working on, my tests run and complete successfully, but when Semaphore attempts to upload my code to my Amazon Elastic Beanstalk instance, I get the error:

> The version of application code on Elastic Beanstalk does not match the version that Semaphore sent in this deployment. Please check your AWS Elastic Beanstalk Console for more information.

With the JSON object printed:

```
{
"Environments": [
    {
        "ApplicationName": "my-app-server", 
        "EnvironmentName": "myappserver", 
        "VersionLabel": "Sample Application", 
        "Status": "Ready", 
        "EnvironmentLinks": [], 
        "EnvironmentId": "my_environment_id", 
        "EndpointURL": "my_server_ip", 
        "SolutionStackName": "64bit Amazon Linux 2016.03 v2.1.0 running Node.js", 
        "CNAME": "my_cname", 
        "Health": "Red", 
        "AbortableOperationInProgress": false, 
        "Tier": {
            "Version": " ", 
            "Type": "Standard", 
            "Name": "WebServer"
        }, 
        "HealthStatus": "Degraded", 
        "DateUpdated": "2016-04-14T16:10:46.905Z", 
        "DateCreated": "2016-04-14T15:44:41.965Z"
    }
]
```

}

*NOTE: I have left out some details to hide the identity of my EB instance.*

I am unsure as to why I am getting this error as I am deploying to a blank Elastic Beanstalk instance running Node.js.  Surely if I have not configured an environment, the deployment should hit EB and install itself successfully?

I followed the semaphore guide [found here](https://semaphoreci.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-node-js-application-to-elastic-beanstalk-with-semaphore) to attempt to deploy my application.

Comment: Can you share the events from your AWS console? Your HealthStatus is Degraded, so there should be some info about why that happened. You should also check the logs at the AWS console, that’s where you’ll most likely find the source of the problem. Btw that error message that Semaphore shows you is because deploy wasn't successfully updated your application code.

Comment: @rastasheep I have an slight idea as to what the problem is.  Semaphore CI is sending the node code with node version 4.3.2, but Elastic beanstalk only supports up to 4.3.0.  I've looked at other version that EB supports, but Semaphore is ALWAYS .2 of a version ahead.  I deployed my code manually and everything runs fine.  Any ideas?

Comment: If you need some specific node version you can easily switch or install particular one with additional command in your deployment for example `nvm install 4.3.0`

Comment: But elastic beanstalk does not support the versions compatible with semaphore

Comment: I understand, but you can install any version on semaphore "manually" by adding command that i've mentioned aboce.

Comment: Ohhh interesting, where in the semaphore UI do I put the command `nvm install 4.3.0`?  Sorry, I'm new to using CI platforms :)

Comment: No worries, just go to the server page, and there you can find "edit server" link, and there you can set mentioned command as first one. It will download install and activate desired version.

Comment: Thank-you so much @rastasheep adding nvm install 4.3.0 to my build sequence, along with an npm update fixed my problem.

Comment: Awesome, don't hesitate to contact our (Semaphore's) support if you have any other question or issue, we're always glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post, but I just ran into this issue which seemed to just be a generic EB deployment issue where this error message is misleading. I have custom commands that run from a `.ebextentions` file and when one of these commands fails, I get the error:

> The version of application code on Elastic Beanstalk does not match the version that Semaphore sent in this deployment